# Solr: Can you assign entire doc to a single field (one that is not found in the document)?

Tags: python, solr

I have to put many different docs (xls,pptx,txt,csv,pdf) into a solr core.  All of the documents are unstructured and unrelated.  I would like to do something like:

```
{
    'filename':'doc1',
    'content': entire doc
}
```

In this case `filename` is not a tag inside the actual document but is assigned by the user and `content`, also not in actual document, would map to the entire indexed document.

I plan on doing the processing through a python script, and while there are tools to extract text from rich text documents, I would rather just pass them to solr and have solr ignore their internal tags (in pdfs for example) and map the whole doc to the `contents` tag of the above schema.

In summation how do I create a schema with two fields not found in the target documents, and index the entire document and map it to one of the fields (`text_en`)?  I'm somewhat new to solr, so my vocabulary might be a little cloudy, so please ask for clarification if you're not sure what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: An alternative is to index the docs as is into solr and create a catch-all copyfield into which you'll copy the contents of all the other fields. Also, on a separate note, `text_en` by default is a fieldType and not a field.

Comment: Like <copyField source="*"  dest="text" />?

Comment: I don't think a wildcard will work here. You will have to add all the fields separately.

Comment: Turns out the wild card works.  I thing _text_ field does the same.

Answer (score 0):

The [Tika module in Solr has configuration options](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika#UploadingDatawithSolrCellusingApacheTika-InputParameters) that should be able to do what you want:

> **literal.<fieldname>**: Populates a field with the name supplied with the specified value for each document. The data can be
>   multivalued if the field is multivalued.

So if you add a parameter named `literal.filename=doc1`, `doc1` will be added in `filename` for the document.

There's also an example to ignore all fields that are not present in the schema:

> **uprefix**: Prefixes all fields that are not defined in the schema with the given prefix. This is very useful when combined with dynamic
>   field definitions. Example: `uprefix=ignored_` would effectively ignore
>   all unknown fields generated by Tika given the example schema contains
>   `<dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored"/>`

And to move a field into a different field name:

> **fmap.<source_field>**: Maps (moves) one field name to another. The `source_field` must be a field in incoming documents, and the
>   value is the Solr field to map to. Example: `fmap.content=text` causes
>   the data in the `content` field generated by Tika to be moved to the
>   Solr's `text` field

And a final hint - to fully customize the handling, but still use the available Solr server and Tika for processing documents (and then knead the data a bit more before indexing):

> **extractOnly**: Default is false. If true, returns the extracted content from Tika without indexing the document. (See also
>   *extractFormat*)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matt!  A clarifying question: Say  I only care about retrieving 'filename' after searching for a document.  I would create a core and add 'filename' (I use the schema api) to the schema, then add a bunch of different docs (word, csv, pdf, pptx,etc) to the core all the while specifying literal.filename=some_unique_filename for each document as I add it. This should do the trick correct?  Is there any reason I need to worry about all the other fields that get automatically created for each unrelated doc I add, if I really just care about the filename?  Thanks again.

Comment: No, the only consequence would be the extra bytes of storage (and a slightly larger index to query), but you probably won't see any practical real world change.